# Fastest way to find index of differences in two arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I need to find the differences between 2 non-sorted byte arrays. The arrays are going to be fairly good size, approximately 300k elements.

The values in the arrays will repeat, so I can't sort it.

These arrays will be the same length. I only need the indexes of the differences.

Do I have to iterate through each array element with a for loop?

Is there a better way?

I currently loop through each element with a for loop, but I just feel like there has to be a better way.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why would the fact that values repeat stop you from sorting them?

Comment: He needs the indexes of where the values are different, so if has `5,1,1,5` compared to `1,5,5,1` sorting that doesn't give him the answer he needs

Comment: In terms of performance, you're probably best off just using a for loop like you already are doing

Comment: int[] arrayA = { 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 };
            int[] arrayB = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 };
            int[] diff = arrayA.Select((x, i) => x - arrayB[i]).ToArray();

Comment: @jdweng if you run that code it just produces an array of 5 ints, all ones

Comment: i have edited my answer with exact solution...

Comment: Isn't that what you are suppose to get?

Comment: @jdweng given your example, the resulting array should be `{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}`, OP asked for the array indexes where values do not match

Comment: Difference can mean two different things.  It is not clear in description if OP wanted a subtraction or 'not match'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the FASTEST way to do this is your end goal, a for loop sounds like the most straight forward way to accomplish this:

```
public static List<int> GetDifferentIndexes(byte[] arr1, byte[] arr2)
{
   // List to hold indexes of differences
   List<int> lstDiffs = new List<int>();

   // Assure neither array is null and lengths match
   if (arr1?.Length == arr2?.Length)
   {  
      // Loop through both arrays and check each value
      for (int idx = 0; idx < arr1.Length; idx++)
      {
         if (arr1[idx] != arr2[idx])
         {
            // Add index to list since values do not match
            lstDiffs.Add(idx);
         }
      }    
   }

   // Your list of different indexes
   return (lstDiffs);
}
```

Comment: OP said "These arrays will be the same length. I only need the indexes of the differences."

Please explain how this answer is incorrect

Comment: Thanks for the help. That's what I've done. It just feels so clumsy.

Comment: Curious: what is the logic behind `return (lstDiffs);` vs. `return lstDiffs;`?

Comment: @ja72 just a force of habit, I always put the return in `( )` for consistency

Comment: @Hyren123 if the result is used only once, it is faster to **not** save it and just use it directly in the If statement. Otherwise, at least set the capacity of the list to something close to the average number of differences `= new List<int>(arr1.Length / 2);`. Even then it is still not the fastest, but the fastest is not worth the trouble (unsafe code with pointers, SIMD or GPU instructions, parallel processing, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to do this with LINQ for the fun of it. I used three passes to achieve the result

1. Zip and check for equality.
2. Encode index if not equal or -1 otherwise
3. Filter the result for values that are not -1

Here is the code you can try:

```
public static int[] GetIndexOfDifferences<T>(T[] array1, T[] array2) where T : IEquatable<T>
{
    var diff_check = array1.Zip(array2, (x, y) => x.Equals(y));
    var get_index = Enumerable.Range(0, array1.Length).Zip(diff_check, (i, z) => z ? -1 : i);
    return get_index.Where((i) => i>=0).ToArray();
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var a = new[] { 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 5, 6, 3, 3, 2, 2 };
    var b = new[] { 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2 };
    // equals?      Y  Y  N  Y  N  Y  N  N  Y  N  N  N  Y
    // index:       0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
    // expected result = { 2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11 }

    var result = GetIndexOfDifferences(a, b); // check
}
```

Comment: Cool approach, roughly 4x faster than the other LINQ answer by @Nino

Comment: nice approach.I will check that out.

Answer (score 0):

this can be simply done using intersection / exclusion, which case suits you more. Take a look at this examples (both arrays have numbers 5 and 7 and other elements are different).

```
int[] arrayA = { 2, 5, 7, 8, 10 }; 
int[] arrayB = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 };

//this will contain all elements that are in both arrays
var sameElements = arrayA.Intersect(arrayB);
//elements that are in array A, but not in array B
var exceptElements = arrayA.Except(arrayB);
//elements from array A and array B but not in both
var nonintersect = arrayA.Except(arrayB).Union(arrayB.Except(arrayA));
```

EDIT: since OP asked for indexes (and I didn't read careful enough), that could be easily achieved with (almost) one-liner:

```
//data - arrays are same on all elements except third and last one (indexes 2 and 4).
int[] arrayA = { 1, 3, 6, 7, 8 };
int[] arrayB = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 };

List<int> listA = arrayA.ToList();
var differentIndexes = listA.Where(a => a != arrayB[listA.IndexOf(a)]).Select(a => listA.IndexOf(a));
```

Comment: OP asked for the indexes of the differences.. not the values

Comment: You would probably want to tag a `.ToList()` on the end of those also, FWIW

Comment: @BackDoorNoBaby since OP asked for values, I have edited my answer. And, no, I do not want ToList() because that's IEnumberable.

Comment: What's wrong with `IEnumerable`?

Comment: The values are not sorted and have duplicates. You cannot use `IndexOf()` per _OP_ description.

Comment: @ja72 confirmed. On a sample of 300K random bytes, Nino's solution finds 296,461 differences, the other answers are equal at 298,803

Comment: @BackDoorNoBaby I wanted to say that `ToList` is not necessary because all those collections are `IEnumberable<string>` and `List<string>` implements `IEnumberable`. Doesn't matter, `ToList()` is legit and ok. Interesting that there are different results with your and mine solution. Anyway, here's an upvote for your approach.